# aws instance recovery vs reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

The Cloudwatch docs show its possible, based on the outcome of an alarm, to (amongst others) either reboot, or recover an instance. What is the difference between a reboot and a recovery?
The docs say:

> A recovered instance is identical to the original instance, including the instance ID, private IP addresses, Elastic IP addresses, and all instance metadata.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html

But from the tests I have done, that is the case for rebooted instances too.

Answer (score 5):

Just found what I needed, But Ill leave this here for others searching for the same thing.
Recovery will move the instance to a new hypervisor, rebooting keeps the instance on the same hypervisor.

Comment: Correct.  Rebooting an instance on a failed supervisor does nothing... it is analogous to pressing control-alt-delete.  Ephemeral storage is lost on a "recovery" but survives a reboot.